how to use intearctive grid with 2 tables (1 from them is view )
i have a view and table
the table contain comment column i need with grid to only modify this column
this is my report query
select a.*,b.COMMENTS,b.id,b.CREATED_BY,b.CREATED_DATE,b.UPDATED_BY,b.UPDATED_DATE,b.REPORT_ID
 from AP_SEC_HOLD a 
left outer join AP_SECTION_WISE_COMMENTS b 
on(a.UNIQ_ID=b.REPORT_ID and REPORT_NAME= 'Accounts Payables - HOLD')

and i use this proccess
'BEGIN
    CASE :APEX$ROW_STATUS
        WHEN 'U' THEN
            IF :REPORT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
                UPDATE AP_SECTION_WISE_COMMENTS
                SET COMMENTS = :comments,
                    UPDATED_BY = :app_user,
                    UPDATED_DATE = SYSDATE
                WHERE REPORT_ID = :REPORT_ID
                and id=:id
                AND REPORT_NAME = 'Accounts Payables - HOLD';
ELSE
                INSERT INTO AP_SECTION_WISE_COMMENTS (COMMENTS, REPORT_ID, REPORT_NAME, CREATED_DATE)
                VALUES (:comments, :uniq_id, 'Accounts Payables - HOLD', SYSDATE);
END IF;
    END CASE;
END;'

the update is work correct but the insert NOT work fine.
I need solution to modify update or insert only the comment column .
the primary key for AP_SECTION_WISE_COMMENTS
IS id
the connection between the table and the view
is (a.UNIQ_ID=b.REPORT_ID )

Why are you doing ":APEX$ROW_STATUS WHEN 'U' " ? That means you are only picking up rows that are updated - hence the 'U'. For new rows APEX$ROW_STATUS will be 'I' (insert)
